# Entity Framework Performance Issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, performance-testing

I am running into an interesting performance issue with Entity Framework. I am using Code First.

Here is the structure of my entities:

A Book can have many Reviews.
A Review is associated with a single Book.
A Review can have one or many Comments.
A Comment is associated with one Review.

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    // ...
    public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class Review 
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
     public int CommentId { get; set; }
     public int ReviewId { get; set; }
     public Review Review { get; set; }
}
```

I populated my database with a lot of data and added the proper indexes. I am trying to retrieve a single book that has 10,000 reviews on it using this query:

```
var bookAndReviews = db.Books.Where(b => b.BookId == id)
                       .Include(b => b.Reviews)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

This particular book has 10,000 reviews. The performance of this query is around 4 seconds. Running the exact same query (via SQL Profiler) actually returns in no time at all. I used the same query and a SqlDataAdapter and custom objects to retrieve the data and it happens in under 500 milliseconds.

Using ANTS Performance Profiler it looks like a bulk of the time is being spent doing a few different things:

**The Equals method is being called 50 million times.**

Does anyone know why it would need to call this 50 million times and how I could increase the performance for this?

Comment: Did you actually look to see what query is being generated by your statement or are you assuming it is the optimal query?

Comment: The problem is not the query like I have stated. I took the exact query that EF is generating and used it in a Sql Data Adapter using regular ADO.net, loading up the same objects manually. It runs in less than a second.

Comment: What's the IL look like?

Comment: Your navigation properties should be marked `virtual`. I'm not sure if that's related or not.

Comment: @Yuck - Only if you want lazy loading, which I don't.

Comment: So... `This particular book has 10,000 reviews.` and you don't want lazy loading. You don't see that as a problem? Not to mention your circular reference in `Book` and `Review`.

Comment: @Yuck - No. I do not want lazy loading. I want to eagerly load all 10,000 records so I can determine if we can use this in our application. We will have scenarios where we will need to load extremely large object graphs. I don't see how making it lazily loaded vs eagerly would improve this.

Comment: @Derek - Tried EF Profiler. From what I can tell it also shows the query executing fast but just gives me a warning that "a large number of objects are being returned." It doesn't tell me why Equals is being called so many times and how I can avoid that.

Comment: Very helpful for issues such as this Performance Considerations for Entity Framework 4, 5, and 6. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-jm/data/hh949853.aspx#2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Why is Equals called 50M times?

It sounds quite suspicious. You have 10.000 reviews and 50.000.000 calls to `Equals`. Suppose that this is caused by identity map internally implemented by EF. Identity map ensures that each entity with unique key is tracked by the context only once so if context already has instance with the same key as loaded record from the database it will not materialize new instance and instead uses the existing one. Now how this can coincide with those numbers? My terrifying guess:

```
=============================================
1st      record read   |  0     comparisons
2nd      record read   |  1     comparison
3rd      record read   |  2     comparisons
...
10.000th record read   |  9.999 comparisons
```

That means that each new record is compared with every existing record in identity map. By applying math to compute sum of all comparison we can use something called "Arithmetic sequence":

```
a(n) = a(n-1) + 1
Sum(n) = (n / 2) * (a(1) + a(n))
Sum(10.000) = 5.000 * (0 + 9.999) => 5.000 * 10.000 = 50.000.000
```

I hope I didn't make mistake in my assumptions or calculation. Wait! I hope I did mistake because this doesn't seem good.

Try turning off change tracking = hopefully turning off identity map checking.

It can be tricky. Start with:

```
var bookAndReviews = db.Books.Where(b => b.BookId == id)
                             .Include(b => b.Reviews)
                             .AsNoTracking()
                             .FirstOrDefault();
```

But there is a big chance that your navigation property will not be populated (because it is handled by change tracking). In such case use this approach:

```
var book = db.Books.Where(b => b.BookId == id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
book.Reviews = db.Reviews.Where(r => r.BookId == id).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Anyway can you see what object type is passed to Equals? I think it should compare only primary keys and even 50M integer comparisons should not be such a problem.

As a side note EF is slow - it is well known fact. It also uses reflection internally when materializing entities so simply 10.000 records can take "some time". Unless you already did that you can also turn off dynamic proxy creation (`db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled`).

Comment: Awesome analysis! According to tests (simple entity with no nav. properties) I've made some time ago, `AsNoTracking` cuts down the time for materialization to 50%. I could imagine though that snapshot creation for entities loaded as tracked is more expensive than calling `Equals` in the identity map. If you call the same query a second time (both as tracked) in the same context it returns fast (less than 1/10 of the first call), much faster than loading without tracking - which lets me guess that the `Equals` check in the identity map is relatively cheap.

Comment: BTW: `Include` works also with `AsNoTracking()`, the navigation collection gets populated. (Or did you mean that the reverse navigation property `Review.Book` will not be populated?)

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds lame, but have you tried the other way around, e.g.:

```
var reviewsAndBooks = db.Reviews.Where(r => r.Book.BookId == id)
                       .Include(r => r.Book);
```

I have noticed sometimes better performance from EF when you approach your queries this way (but I haven't had the time to figure out why).

Comment: I would personally avoid this due to issues with deadlocks.