# CodeFirst loading 1 parent linked to 25 000 children is slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first

I searched a lot on my performance problem and tried all sorts of different things, but I just can't seem to get it to work fast enough.  Here's my problem to it's simplest form:

I'm using entity framework 5 and I want to be able to lazy load child instances of a parent when the user selects that parent, so I don't have to pull the entire database.  However I have been having performance problems with lazy loading the children.  I think the problem is the wire up of the navigation properties between the Parent and the children.  I'm also thinking it must be something I did wrong because I believe this is a simple case.

So I put up a program to test a single lazy load to isolate the problem.

Here's the Test:

I created a POCO Parent class and a Child POCO Class.  Parent has n Children and Child has 1 Parent.  There's only 1 parent in the SQL Server database and 25 000 children for that single parent.  I tried different methods to load this data.  Whenever I load either the children and the parent in the same DbContext, it takes a really long time.  But if I load them in different DbContexts, it loads really fast.  However, I want those instances to be in the same DbContext.

**Here is my test setup and everything you need to replicate it:**

**POCOs:**

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext:**

```
public class Entities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

**TSQL Script to create the Database and data:**

```
USE [master]
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.databases
    WHERE name = 'PerformanceParentChild')
    alter database [PerformanceParentChild] set single_user with rollback immediate
    DROP DATABASE [PerformanceParentChild]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [PerformanceParentChild]
GO
USE [PerformanceParentChild]
GO
BEGIN TRAN T1;
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parents]
(
    [ParentId] [int] CONSTRAINT PK_Parents PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] [nvarchar](200) NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Children]
(
    [ChildId] [int] CONSTRAINT PK_Children PRIMARY KEY,
    [ParentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](200) NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO Parents (ParentId, Name)
VALUES (1, 'Parent')

DECLARE @nbChildren int;
DECLARE @childId int;

SET @nbChildren = 25000;
SET @childId = 0;

WHILE @childId < @nbChildren
BEGIN
   SET @childId = @childId + 1;
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Children] (ChildId, ParentId, Name)
   VALUES (@childId, 1, 'Child #' + convert(nvarchar(5), @childId))
END

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ParentId] ON [dbo].[Children] 
(
    [ParentId] ASC
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Children] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Children.Parents_ParentId] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Parents] ([ParentId])
GO

COMMIT TRAN T1;
```

**App.config containing the connection string:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="Entities"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=PerformanceParentChild;Trusted_Connection=true;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**Test console class:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Parent> parents;
        List<Child> children;

        Entities entities;
        DateTime before;
        TimeSpan childrenLoadElapsed;
        TimeSpan parentLoadElapsed;

        using (entities = new Entities())
        {
            before = DateTime.Now;
            parents = entities.Parents.ToList();
            parentLoadElapsed = DateTime.Now - before;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load only the parent from DbSet:" + parentLoadElapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds");
        }

        using (entities = new Entities())
        {
            before = DateTime.Now;
            children = entities.Childs.ToList();
            childrenLoadElapsed = DateTime.Now - before;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load only the children from DbSet:" + childrenLoadElapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds");
        }

        using (entities = new Entities())
        {
            before = DateTime.Now;
            parents = entities.Parents.ToList();
            parentLoadElapsed = DateTime.Now - before;

            before = DateTime.Now;
            children = entities.Childs.ToList();
            childrenLoadElapsed = DateTime.Now - before;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load the parent from DbSet:" + parentLoadElapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds" +
                                               ", then load the children from DbSet:" + childrenLoadElapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds");
        }

        using (entities = new Entities())
        {
            before = DateTime.Now;
            children = entities.Childs.ToList();
            childrenLoadElapsed = DateTime.Now - before;

            before = DateTime.Now;
            parents = entities.Parents.ToList();
            parentLoadElapsed = DateTime.Now - before;


            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load the children from DbSet:" + childrenLoadElapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds" +
                                               ", then load the parent from DbSet:" + parentLoadElapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds");
        }

        using (entities = new Entities())
        {
            before = DateTime.Now;
            parents = entities.Parents.ToList();
            parentLoadElapsed = DateTime.Now - before;

            before = DateTime.Now;
            children = parents[0].Childs;
            childrenLoadElapsed = DateTime.Now - before;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load the parent from DbSet:" + parentLoadElapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds" +
                                               ", then load the children from Parent's lazy loaded navigation property:" + childrenLoadElapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds");
        }

        using (entities = new Entities())
        {
            before = DateTime.Now;
            parents = entities.Parents.Include(p => p.Childs).ToList();
            parentLoadElapsed = DateTime.Now - before;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load the parent from DbSet and children from include:" + parentLoadElapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds");

        }

        using (entities = new Entities())
        {
            entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            entities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            entities.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            entities.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

            before = DateTime.Now;
            parents = entities.Parents.Include(p => p.Childs).ToList();
            parentLoadElapsed = DateTime.Now - before;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load the parent from DbSet and children from include:" + parentLoadElapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds with everything turned off");

        }

    }
}
```

**Here are the results of those test:**

Load only the parent from DbSet:0,972 seconds

Load only the children from DbSet:0,714 seconds

Load the parent from DbSet:0,001 seconds, then load the children from DbSet:8,6026 seconds

Load the children from DbSet:0,6864 seconds, then load the parent from DbSet:7,5816159 seconds

Load the parent from DbSet:0 seconds, then load the children from Parent's lazy loaded navigation property:8,5644549 seconds

Load the parent from DbSet and children from include:8,6428788 seconds

Load the parent from DbSet and children from include:9,1416586 seconds with everything turned off

**Analysis**

Whenever the parent and the children are in the same DbContext, it takes a long time (9 seconds) to wire everything up.  I even tried turning off everything from proxy creation to lazy loading, but to no avail.  Can someone please help me ?

Comment: +1: Great question and analysis!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403149/entity-framework-performance-issue/7404958#7404958) previously. My previous answer contains theory answering this issue but with your detailed question I can directly point where the issue is. First lets run one of the problematic cases with performance profiler. This is result from DotTrace when using tracing mode:

[image]

Fixing relations runs in loop. It means that for 25.000 records you have 25.000 iterations but each of these iterations internally calls `CheckIfNavigationPropertyContainsEntity` on `EntityCollection`:

```
internal override bool CheckIfNavigationPropertyContainsEntity(IEntityWrapper wrapper)
{
    if (base.TargetAccessor.HasProperty)
    {
        object navigationPropertyValue = base.WrappedOwner.GetNavigationPropertyValue(this);
        if (navigationPropertyValue != null)
        {
            if (!(navigationPropertyValue is IEnumerable))
            {
                throw new EntityException(Strings.ObjectStateEntry_UnableToEnumerateCollection(base.TargetAccessor.PropertyName, base.WrappedOwner.Entity.GetType().FullName));
            }
            foreach (object obj3 in navigationPropertyValue as IEnumerable)
            {
                if (object.Equals(obj3, wrapper.Entity))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Number of iterations of inner loop grows as items are added to the navigation property. The math is in my previous answer - it is arithmetic series where the total number of iterations of inner loop is 1/2 * (n^2 - n) => n^2 complexity. The inner loop inside the outer loop results in 312.487.500 iterations in your case as also the performance tracing shows.

I created [work item on EF CodePlex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/591) for this issue.

Comment: That is a great answer, thanks a lot.  I am also grateful you created a work item on EF CodePlex.

Answer (score 5):

This is not answer as I don't have a solution to improve the performance, but the comment section doesn't have enough space for the following. I just want to add a few additional tests and observations.

First, I could reproduce your measured times almost exactly for all seven tests. I have used EF 4.1 for the test.

Some interesting things to note:

- From (the fast) test 2 I would conclude that object materialization (converting the rows and columns returned from the database server into objects) isn't slow.
- This is also confirmed by loading the entities in test 3 without change tracking:

  ```
  parents = entities.Parents.AsNoTracking().ToList();
  // ...
  children = entities.Childs.AsNoTracking().ToList();
  ```

  This code runs fast although 25001 objects have to be materialized as well (but no relationships between the navigation properties will be established!).
- Also from (the fast) test 2 I would conclude that creating entity snapshots for change tracking isn't slow.
- In tests 3 and 4 the relationships between the parent and the 25000 children get fixed up when the entities are loaded from the database, i.e. EF adds all the `Child` entities to the parent's `Childs` collection and sets the `Parent` in each child to the loaded parent. Apparently this step is slow, as you already guessed:

  > I think the problem is the wire up of the navigation properties
  >   between the Parent and the children.

  Especially the collection side of the relationship seems to be the problem: If you comment out the `Childs` navigation property in the `Parent` class (the relationship is still a required one-to-many relationship then) tests 3 and 4 are fast, although EF still sets the `Parent` property for all 25000 `Child` entities.

  I don't know why filling up the navigation collection during relationship fixup is so slow. If you simulate it manually in a naive manner, like so...

  ```
  entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

  children = entities.Childs.AsNoTracking().ToList();
  parents = entities.Parents.AsNoTracking().ToList();

  parents[0].Childs = new List<Child>();
  foreach (var c in children)
  {
      if (c.ParentId == parents[0].ParentId)
      {
          c.Parent = parents[0];
          parents[0].Childs.Add(c);
      }
  }
  ```

  ... it goes fast. Obviously relationship fixup internally doesn't work this simple way. Maybe it needs to be checked if the collection already contains the child to be tested:

  ```
  foreach (var c in children)
  {
      if (c.ParentId == parents[0].ParentId)
      {
          c.Parent = parents[0];
          if (!parents[0].Childs.Contains(c))
              parents[0].Childs.Add(c);
      }
  }
  ```

  This is significantly slower (around 4 seconds).

Anyway, relationship fixup seems to be the performance botteneck. I don't know how to improve it if you need change tracking and correct relations between your attached entities.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a hand!  I will edit the post with your comments and additional analysis.  I will also format my analysis like you did, it is a lot clearer what test was used to deduce a point.

Comment: I also put up another test while I was waiting for some help.  I created an NHibernate data access layer that uses the same POCOs and test code as this one (except the last 2), and each test runs under the 1 second mark.

Comment: @CurlyFire: Does NHibernate fixup the relations automatically? For example, in test 3, does NH set `Child.Parent` and `Parent.Childs` for all loaded entities to the correct objects?

Comment: Yes it sure looks like it.  I included two more lines of code after the loading of the children (get the count of parents[0].Child and get the Parent from children[0].Parent) to make sure the properties were loaded and wired up, and the time difference was negligeable.  I could edit this question and put the comparison between Entity Framework and NHibernate or leave NHibernate out of it.  What do you think ?